# Ubuntu 23.04 Freezes selecting Settings with connected Lenovo dock

Tags: lenovo, settings, 23.04

Lenovo X1 Yoga gen 6
Latest Ubuntu 23.04
All up to date.

Attempting to access Settings causes a complete system freeze.

REISUB causes restart.

As a work around I have rebooted with the dock disconnected. This works. I can access Settings fine.

Anyone else with the same problem? This occurred after the latest update.

Answer (score 0):

Resetting* the connection between the laptop and the dock fixed the problem.

*By pulling out the cable, then putting it back in. snafu.